# Node - Attaching to server / websockets

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am running a vue application (VUE-CLI 3) on Node.  In dev mode, I run 'npm run serve' and the application is brought up and works as expected.

I would now like to add websocket code to the server.

Most examples I see have some setup code similar to:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();
const wsServer = new WebsocketServer({httpServer: server});
```

When I run 'npm run serve' I now am greeted with the following error message:

```
'http.createServer is not a function'
```

Is there a way to attach the websockets to the current running node server when invoked via npm run serve? In other words, can I skip the createServer call and attach it to whatever is currently running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code should read something like this...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

You will need to use ExpressJS on the back-end to handle messages.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working by doing that and running it via 'node ../path/to/myServerFile.js' in a separate console window